# ProgressBar animation only showing once

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-animation

In my `MainActivity's xml` file, `activity_main.xml`  I have a `FrameLayout` showing a list of reservations:

```
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/login_progress" style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/home_page_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

When the user wants to eliminate one reservation by clicking on it, the list has to be updated, therefore I perform a call to the network using this method:

```
public void cancelReservation(ReservationResponse rR){
    if (mNetwork != null) {return;}
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        showProgress(true);
        mNetwork = new NetworkTask(this, "cancel_reservation", rR);
        mNetwork.execute((Void) null);
    }else{
        // display error
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "No network available!");
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_network_dialog ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

which updates the `AppEngine` reservations and returns the updated list back to the `Activity`.
Before executing the `AsyncTask` I invoke the method `showProgress`, starting this simple animation:

[image]

the method has a constant duration, during which the `FrameLayout` is hidden in favor of the `ProgressBar`; then in the `ProgressBar`'s `onAnimationEnd` method the `FrameLayout` is restored and the animation is set to `View.GONE`, finally showing the updated list of reservations:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public void showProgress(final boolean showProgr) {
    final FrameLayout home_scroll = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_page_frame);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        mProgressView.destroyDrawingCache();

        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
        home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressView.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime*9).alpha(
                showProgr ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                    home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
        });

    } else {
        home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

> My quirky problem is that while the first time I cancel a reservation the animation is displayed, from the second time onwards every time I cancel a reservation the animation does not appear. How come?

I've tried by invoking this method:

```
        mProgressView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

but it didn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by modifying the way I use the method `showProgress()`.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
public void showProgress(final boolean showProgr) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    final FrameLayout home_scroll = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_page_frame);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

        mProgressView.refreshDrawableState();//setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(showProgr) {
            home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mProgressView.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate();

        }else{
            mProgressView.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.invalidate();
            mProgressView.clearAnimation();
            mProgressView.setActivated(false);
            home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else { //TODO debug <= HONEYCOMB
        home_scroll.setVisibility(showProgr ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Before I was using the method by setting a short animation and waiting for it to finish by itself. Insead, by not setting a timer and calling the `showProgress` method two times, first when the animation has to start with `showProgress(true)`, and second when it has to end with `showProgress(false)`, it then all works nicely.